# Replace the first column of a text file to be 6 minus the current value

Tags: text-processing

I have the following file, space separated

```
2.5   235215           3.1925
3.7   125255           1.3125
```

I need to change the first column to be 6 minus the current value. The desired result is

```
3.5   235215           3.1925
2.3   125255           1.3125
```

How to do this with a Bash script?

I tried

```shell
$KMAX=6
sed -E "s/^(([^ ]+ +){3})$1  /\1$KMAX-$1 /" $1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is solved easily using `awk`:

```
awk -v kmax=6 '{$1=kmax-$1}1' file.txt
```

- This will import the value `6` into an `awk` variable `kmax` which can then be used internally.
- The program will replace the first column `$1` by the arithmetic result of `kmax-$1`.
- The seemingly "stray" `1` outside of the action block results in the current line being printed, including all modifications made.

One caveat: for space-separated columns, `awk` will only use *one* space as separator on output, so the result will be in your case:

```
3.5 235215 3.1925
2.3 125255 1.3125
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'given .split( / \s+ /) { put join "\t", (6 - .[0], .[1..*])  };'
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne 'given .split( / \s+ /) { join("\t", (6 - .[0], .[1..*])).put };'
```

Raku is a Perl-family programming language. An advantage of using Raku is that it can easily handle one-liners, and if you need to step up to more serious CSV processing, you can use a module (e.g. `Text::CSV`).

Above the code is invoked with the `-ne` non-autoprinting, linewise flags. The `given` keyword tells Raku to treat the input as one item (a line), while `split`ting on whitespace. Within the block, 6 is subtracted from the `.[0]` first element, and the result placed in a list with `.[1..*]` the remaining elements. Finally, the output is printed with `put`.

Sample Input:

```
2.5   235215           3.1925
3.7   125255           1.3125
```

Sample Output:

```
3.5 235215  3.1925
2.3 125255  1.3125
```

https://raku.org